# DTM - appending custom events to page load events

Tags: javascript, analytics, adobe-analytics, web-analytics

I am struggling to fire custom event (from custom code) along with my page load events.
e.g. When my home page loads I want to trigger event 1 and if my dataelement meets certain condition it should trigger event2. So in my call in debugger I should see event1,event2.

But whats happening is my pageload rule is getting overwritten by custom event so I only get event2 in debugger.

Question is how do we append events to page load rule events.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution - we need to use s.apl plugin in scode to append events.

Good luck!

Comment: s.apl plugin should do the trick but just for general clarification the plugin isn't needed. You can add a condition to your page load rule that will append events.

Answer (score 1):

The s.apl plugin should work fine when included as part of "do_plugins"but just for general clarification that plugin isn't necessarily needed. You could add a condition within the custom page editor of your rule that looks for the value of your Data Element and then appends the additional event. For example:

```
//Check for value of Data Element as page load rule executes

if(_satellite.getVar('My_Data_Element')) {

//Append additional event

s.events = s.events+',eventX';
}
```

If you try and evaluate this condition as part of your DE instead of using custom page code you will find issues with timing and execution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The s.apl plugin is convenient to ensure that the existing values are preserved, properly formatted, and no duplicates are present. If you set s.events manually, make sure that you also set s.linkTrackEvents and add "events" to s.linkTrackVars. Usage looks like: s.linkTrackEvents=s.events=s.apl(s.events,"event9",",",1); s.linkTrackVars=s.apl(s.linkTrackVars,"events",",",1);

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in easier way:

1) Create page load rule where you set condition criteria Data Element Value,
and according to condition use proper event in events section. 
Even couple of rules will be combined into single image request to Adobe Analytics.

2) In custom code section you can add condition and add line:

```
s.events = s.events + ',eventN';
```

where N is your desired event number.